# ASP.NET GridView Paging using Linq query as datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, paging

I am looking for a way to do paging with a GridView when i set the datasource at run time using a linq query.  here is my code:

```
ETDataContext etdc = new ETDataContext();
var accts = from a in etdc.ACCOUNTs
            orderby  a.account_id
            select new
            {
                Account = a.account_id,
                aType = a.SERVICEs.FirstOrDefault().SERVICE_TYPE.service_type_desc,
                name = a.SERVICEs.FirstOrDefault().service_name,
                Letter_dt = a.create_dt,
                PrimAccthldr = a.PEOPLE.first_name + " " + a.PEOPLE.middle_name + " " + a.PEOPLE.last_name
             };
GridView1.DataSource = accts;
GridView1.BindData();
```

I have the grid set to allow paging, but I get an error that says that the PageIndexChanging event has not been handled.  I searched around and found the following:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
     GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But that works well when you use a datatable but not with linq.  If I add a rebind in the event, it has to requery 7000 records which can be a little slow.  Does anyone know how to fix the paging when using linq like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/gridview-objectdatasource-linq-paging-and-sorting

http://www.dbtutorials.com/display/linq-to-sql-paging-cs.aspx

Other possibility here:

Use LINQ Data Source as described by Scott Guthrie (the father of ASP)
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx

Comment: nope not using a DAL or objectdatasource object for this.  Just simply creating an anonymous type with linq then binding straight to the grid.

Comment: If wanna follow this way you'll have poor performance. It's not the proper way of doing this... You should use a LINQ Data Source for example that gives you support for an efficient paging.

Comment: I can't link multiple tables using the linqdatasource otherwise I'd just bind to that.  do you know a way to use the linqdatasource to do this query?  The data comes from 4 different tables.

Comment: You definitely can. Read this one: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx. Go to this part: Using the <asp:LinqDataSource> Selecting Event

Comment: using selecting event on linqdatasource to add custom query worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: An anonymous user wanted to add this to the answer, but I thought it might be better suited as a comment: *Add in gridview* `onpageindexchanging="dgvReport_PageIndexChanging"` *then perfectly working!!*