# How to increase the Performance of the Select query fetching Huge data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want fetch a huge data on site (about 19000 record) and show that on datalist control.
my data list have a paging feature and on the first time i show only 6 record on datalist.
then he user can go to page 2 and 3 and ...
fetch all record to data table get more time.
Please help me in details what should i use in sql server.

```
private void FetchDataToDataList()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (Cache["DataTable-cach"] == null)
    {
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.table_name.field_name, FROM dbo.table_name ", con);
        con.Open();
        dt = new DataTable("T");
        string startime = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        string endtime = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        Cache.Insert("DataTable-cach", dt, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        con.Close();
    }
    else 
    {
        dt = ((DataTable)Cache["DataTable-cach"]);
    }

    // pagedDS is data list control
    PagedDataSource pagedDS = new PagedDataSource();
    pagedDS.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    pagedDS.AllowPaging = true;
    pagedDS.PageSize = 6;
    pagedDS.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
    dlPaging.DataSource = pagedDS;
    dlPaging.DataBind();
    lblCurrentPage.Text =  pagedDS.PageCount.ToString() +" صفحه    " +  (CurrentPage + 1).ToString()+ " از " ;
    // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
    cmdPrev.Enabled = !pagedDS.IsFirstPage;
    cmdNext.Enabled = !pagedDS.IsLastPage;
}
```

Comment: you can go through the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580962/asp-net-gridview-paging-using-linq-query-as-datasource) on SO

Comment: You really need to look at using an ORM (Entity Framework, nHibernate) or use a stored procedure and roll your own paging within that. In basic terms you need to stop returning the whole resultset and just return the data you need when you need it.

Comment: Does the sql statement take long time to execute?

Comment: why do you want so much data in the datalist, do your users read really really fast? I suspect you want a small fraction of the total data at a time.

Comment: Use lazy loading , load only those records which you are currently being displayed

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the SQL Server version, you should request only as many records from the database as you need.

In SQL Server 2012 you can use the `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` keywords. In earlier versions, use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I want to use of all records on other place on my web.
therefore  i load all record once time and send all record on cach, ofter i use of cach for get table

Comment: Please elaborate where you need 19,000 records at once.

Comment: In other parts of my website, I use this large table(about 19000 record) and that's why I get all records of database and user must be can filter data, therefore i guess that if i put all records on cache, speed of filter must be better.

Comment: Filtering should also be done on the database. 19,000 records is not a significant amount where caching should bring a measurable performance increase.

Answer (score 1):

Laoding 19,000 records at a time is not a good option beacuse it would take time to build all the html at the same time.

And most importantly you are not going to display all the records at a time.

So, you need to load only those records that are currently being displayed to user.

This tremendously boosts your performance / page load speed.

Write your stored procedure in such a way that you are fetching only required records and not records all at a time.

**Example:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDataPageWise                      // Name of the stored procedure
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY [ColumnName] ASC
      )AS RowNumber
      ,[ColumnName]
      ,[ColumnName]
      ,[ColumnName]
     INTO #Results                              // #Results is the temporary table that we are creating
      FROM [TableName]

      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results                      // Dropping the temporary table results as it is not required furthur
END
GO
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: In other parts of my website, I use this large table(about 19000 record)  and that's why I get all records of database and then put all tecords on  cache 
 according to your answer ,initially is better that i get only 6 record with store procedure and show datalist to user then i must get all  records from the database and put to cache.
 what should i use?

Comment: I guess..it is not appropraite to put 19,000 records in Cache. Do you need all the 19,000 records all at a time later on ?

Comment: user must be can filter data, therefore i guess that if i put all records on cache, speed of filter must be better.whats your idea?

Comment: @user..Your records may not be 19,000 through out, what if they increases to some 40,000. So, you have to consider long term issues when developing code. Therefore, a database call will not be so costly when compared to filtering from cache.More over, Cache memory is used for small amount od data and not huge sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try paging like below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192408/SQL-Pager-Control-for-GridView-DataList-Repeater-D